# Trying to learn basic layout principles (HTML, CSS) - Beginner's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to learning HTML, CSS, and coding in general. I plan on coding a Bootstrap grid system based page, but was wondering how to add this functionality to it. I want a dropdown informational panel to appear (as shown in green) whenever a thumbnail is clicked. I want to achieve this using only HTML and CSS and using least code as possible.

I'd appreciate any sort of help.

Excuse my limited vocabulary in this field. Don't know what to call the "informational panel".

[image: dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) grid system.
It's a great way to get started with the layout of your page. It is simple to use and adapt to your own needs.Their grid system is also responsive.

To get you started with your layout:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Logo</div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  ...
</div>
```

You get the trick...
You need to place the row within a `container` class for proper alignment. Again see [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: Yep. I am somewhat familiar with the Bootstrap grid system. I was mainly looking to learn how to add the dropdown sort of functionality to it with the slideshow element inside.

By the way, do you have any idea what all the downvotes on this site are about? It seems like every question I asked was met by downvotes at first until someone helpful comes along such as yourself.

Comment: It's very good that you are trying to learn some programming concepts and you should continue, of course. I can't speak for the other questions you've wrote but here your question was too broad and your explanation vague. Try being more specific and think about what kind of answer you are seeking.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks. That's some good advice. As I started learning coding very recently I am not familiar with the proper terminology.

Answer (score -1):

OK, the long and short is you are on the right path. HTML and CSS are technologies, while what you seek is an art. http://www.w3schools.com/. learn about the div tag.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with the div tag. Was mainly looking to add the informational panel function when the thumbnail was active (green portion of my attached image).